# How do sets with $\liminf / \limsup$ inside or outside relate?

Tags: probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of random variables. I would like to know what can be said about the relation between $\{\liminf X_n < 0\}$ or $\{\liminf X_n > 0\}$, and the sets formed by any combination of $\liminf, \limsup$, and $<, \leq, \geq, >$, e.g. $\liminf \{ X_n < 0 \}, \limsup \{ X_n > 0 \}...$

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\liminf_n X_n = \sup_n \inf_{k\geq n} X_k$, the sequence $\inf_{k\geq n} X_k$ is monotonically increasing. Hence
$$ \{\liminf_n X_n  \le 0\} = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \{\inf_{k\geq n} X_k< 0\} = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k\geq n} \{X_k< 0\} $$
As for $\{\liminf_n X_n>0\}$: the condition $\liminf_n X_n>0$ means that there is an index $n$ such that $\inf_{k\geq n} X_k >0$, i.e. there is an index $n$ such that for any $k\geq n$ $X_k>0$. Writing in set-formalism yields
$$\{\liminf_n X_n\ge0\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k\geq n} \{X_k>0\}. $$
By definition, for a sequence of sets $A_n$ we denote by
\begin{align*} \limsup_n A_n &= \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k\geq n} A_k \\
\liminf A_n &=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k\geq n} A_k.\end{align*}
Now denote by $A_k = \{X_k>0\}$ and by $B_k=\{X_k<0\}$, then
\begin{align*}
\liminf_n A_n &= \{\liminf_n X_n\ge0\} \\
\limsup_n B_n & =\{\liminf_n X_n\le0\}
\end{align*}
**Update:** 
Now as for $\{\liminf_n X_n>0\}$. This means that there exists $m\in \mathbb N$ and an $N\in \mathbb N$ s.t. for any $n\geq N$ $\{X_k\geq \frac1m\}$, i.e.
$$ \{\liminf_n X_n>0\} = \bigcup_{m\geq 1} \bigcup_{n\geq1} \bigcap_{k\geq n} \{X_k\geq \frac1m\}. $$
$\{\liminf_n X_n <0\}$ can be handled similarily.

Comment: I understand your reasoning, but something disturbs me. In $\liminf_n A_n \subseteq \{ \liminf_n X_n > 0 \}$, one can imagine a sequence that belongs to all but finitely many $A_n$ but $\liminf_n X_n = 0$, e.g. $1/n^2$. Same happens with the second identity and the sequence $-1/n^2$: it belongs to an infinite number of $B_n$ but $\liminf_n X_n = 0$. How does that fit in your reasoning?